# Why redis-py causes high cpu?

Tags: python, concurrency, redis, tornado, redis-py

My website is powered by `tornado`. When doing the stress testing, I found `python3` used almost all cpu while `redis-server` used a little. So, I did a profile, but the profile result makes me confused:

[image: profile result]

It seems that all `redis-py` operations (`r.xxx()` and `lua_xxx()`) takes huge cpu time.

I have no idea why `python3` eats all cpu since if the redis request is blocked, it should sleep thus less cpu usage. So, could you please tell me where could the problem be? Thanks!

Comment: The CPU time seems to be used by `lua_place_order()` but why is hard to say without it's code.

Comment: @KlausD. `lua_place_order()` is a previously registered redis lua script, so I think it should be executed at redis-server, thus does not make python crazy.

Comment: you can get a 17% increase in speed of the string manipulation using .format()  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20746724/1499803

Comment: @Back2Basics Thanks for the tip!